# How to get files in a relative path in C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

If I have an executable called app.exe which is what I am coding in C#, how would I get files from a folder loaded in the same directory as the app.exe, using relative paths?

This throws an illegal characters in path exception:

```
string [ ] files = Directory.GetFiles ( "\\Archive\\*.zip" );
```

How would one do this in C#?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To make sure you have the application's path (and not just the current directory), use this:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx

Now you have a `Process` object that represents the process that is running.

Then use `Process.MainModule.FileName`:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename.aspx

Finally, use `Path.GetDirectoryName` to get the folder containing the .exe:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx

So this is what you want:

```
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\Archive\";
string filter = "*.zip";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, filter);
```

(Notice that `"\Archive\"` from your question is now `@"\Archive\"`: you need the @ so that the `\` backslashes aren't interpreted as the start of an escape sequence)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location); is simpler imo.

Comment: How do you do it for a virtual directory that is in the top root of the web application that is mapped to UNC path?

Answer (score 43):

```
string currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string archiveFolder = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "archive");
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(archiveFolder, "*.zip");
```

The first parameter is the path. The second is the search pattern you want to use.

Comment: Adding to Kieren's comment : there's also things like OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog which can change the current directory at runtime. (if RestoreDirectory property is left at its default value of false).

Comment: Fair point. I updated my answer. @Moe: Good to know. I didn't know RestoreDirectory existed.

Comment: Slightly off topic: note that if you want files in the current directory you cannot pass an empty string as the path argument to Directory.GetFiles, but "." works.

Answer (score 20):

Write it like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@".\Archive", "*.zip");
```

. is for relative to the folder where you started your exe, and @ to allow \ in the name.

When using filters, you pass it as a second parameter. You can also add a third parameter to specify if you want to search recursively for the pattern.

In order to get the folder where your .exe actually resides, use:

```
var executingPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: .\ means relative to the current directory, I think?

Comment: A single dot (.) can stand in for the current directory.  Two dots (..) mean the parent of the current directory.

Comment: Exactly, but the question is talking about relative to the executable, not the current directory..?

Comment: Updated my answer to specify the ., and where your exe resides.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you can/should prepend the string with `@` (though you could also just escape the backslashes), but what they glossed over (that is, didn't bring it up despite making a change related to it) was the fact that, as I recently discovered, using `\` at the beginning of a pathname, without `.` to represent the current directory, refers to the root of the current directory tree.

```
C:\foo\bar>cd \
C:\>
```

versus

```
C:\foo\bar>cd .\
C:\foo\bar>
```

(Using `.` by itself has the same effect as using `.\` by itself, from my experience. I don't know if there are any specific cases where they somehow would not mean the same thing.)

You could also just leave off the leading `.\` , if you want.

```
C:\foo>cd bar
C:\foo\bar>
```

In fact, if you really wanted to, you don't even need to use backslashes. Forwardslashes work perfectly well! (Though a single `/` doesn't alias to the current drive root as `\` does.)

```
C:\>cd foo/bar
C:\foo\bar>
```

You could even alternate them.

```
C:\>cd foo/bar\baz
C:\foo\bar\baz>
```

...I've really gone off-topic here, though, so feel free to ignore all this if you aren't interested.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward, use relative path

```
string[] offerFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/offers"), "*.csv");
```