# How to get image files in c# using relative path?

Tags: c#

I've checked this thread [How to get files in a relative path in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259583/how-to-get-files-in-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp), the directory is in IDE, which is not correct for me. I have a website application, needs to get image files from the same level folder `img`. I can use following code to get them:

```
DirectoryInfo path=new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\WebsiteSolution\wwwroot\Chat\img");
FileInfo[] images = path.GetFiles("*");
```

But I want to use something like `.\img` to replace the parameter in the first line code, is that possible?

Comment: Relative to what--the application's folder?

Answer (score 7):

Call the Server.MapPath utility to get the relative path.

```
DirectoryInfo path = Server.MapPath("~\Chat\img");
```

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.Net use MapPath - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx.

Also if you just need to construct path for rendering a page just /Chat/img/My.gif is enough.

Answer (score -1):

You need to find an anchor - something like `Application.ExecutablePath` - and then use that anchor with `Path.Combine()` to reach your image directory.

If your `Application.ExecutablePath` were: `@"c:\WebSiteSolution\wwwroot\chat\code"`, then you could use `string imgPath = Path.Combine(Application.ExecutablePath, @"..\img");`

If you have a hard time finding a good anchor, there's a bunch to consider. You can get the path of the executing assembly via `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Comment: I would not use this approach for an ASP.NET application hosted in IIS.  For one thing, the ExecutablePath will most likely be some executable under the Windows folder.  Also, I belive that IIS makes a shadow copy of assemblies; I'm not sure how that affects the Assembly.Location property, but the value of it may not be what you expect.  Using HttpServerUtility.MapPath is the standard way of getting a physical file path for a virtual path.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I've had to deal with this problem a lot in desktop application programming, but I don't do much web programming.