# Getting file into specific Folder on C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the application's directory from a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application)

I want to acess files from project directory like in java without using "C:\Path"  because it create file exception into my picture box  this is code into my timer

```
if (imagecount == 30)
{
    this.pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Baloi\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WinEX\WinEX\" + image() + ".jpg");
    imagecount = 0;
}

else if (imagecount < 30)
    imagecount++;
```

Comment: Also similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259583/how-to-get-files-in-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aplication directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx):

```
string baseDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

[Executable Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx):

```
string executableDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Based on your requirement you can use one of above with [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) and build full path to your image location.

Or you can embed images in a resource file. then you can load them as

```
Stream imgStream = 
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
    "YourNamespace.resources.ImageName.bmp");
pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(imgStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code:

```
this.pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(image() + ".jpg");
```

Your file should be in the same folder as the program.

Comment: thanks but image is a  integer return of photo's number

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Embed the pictures in your project (set the compile action to Embedded Data)
2. Reference your pictures using a relative path.  This is complicated slightly by the fact that, while debugging, the binary assemblies are in the bin\Debug folder

For option 1:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream file = 
    thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("AssemblyName.ImageFile.jpg");
this.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(file);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287676(v=vs.71).aspx

For option 2:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    contentDirectory = Path.Combine(appPath + @"\..\..\content");
}
else
{   
    contentDirectory = Path.Combine(appPath, @"content");
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine I asked the same thing  on Codeproject but people only look

Comment: error on picturebox null stream