# How can I find which drive my exe is running from?

Tags: c#

I am writing a c# app that needs to be able to be ran from a usb, and it launches other programs that are installed to the usb. Not necessarily the computer it's being ran on. I am launching these applications by doing:

```
Process.Start("notmyprogram.exe");
```

this works great however I am finding that this only works if `notmyprogram.exe.` is installed to the computers hard drive. If I want to run a program not installed on the computer, but rather to the usb, I have to call it directly, like so:

```
Process.Start("D:\\Programs\\notmyprogram\\applicationinstalledonusb.exe");
```

Where `D:` is the letter assigned by my OS. However, obviously the drive letter changes per computer, it wont always be D. MY application is located on the usb so my question is: is there any way to find what drive letter my exe is ran from so I could then append the directory to the end of the drive letter? Or maybe I'm simply going about it the wrong way and there's a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I've been searching this for the last day, SO is usually my last resort as I find I learn better if I figure it out myself. If this has already been answered then I apologize, but I could not find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get files in a relative path in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259583/how-to-get-files-in-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I think this should be what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Side note: Here is search query that gives you results - not sure what you used that did not find anything: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+relative+executable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this (using System.IO):

```
string root = Path.GetPathRoot(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Also, You can use **[Path.GetFullPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** instead `Path.GetPathRoot()` and remove unwanted part from the string without hardcoding the folder name

Comment: That worked! just have to add the directory to the root now, thanks!

Comment: @nope No need to rebuild the full path. Get the current directory through `Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetFullPath(...))` then use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to navigate from there.

Answer (score 1):

I use to split crurrent directory string and get first element, like the following:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Split('\\')[0]
```