# How to get files from a directory with relative path "Directory.GetFiles(sPath) "

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have relative path of a directory like "..\work\FilesDirectory". How to get all files from this directory.
I am currently using the following line of code but it requiresw absolute path.

```
string []AllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sPath);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259583/how-to-get-files-in-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should you [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to construct absolute path or you can change [Current Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so relative path points to location you need.

```
// Building c:\my\home\work\FilesDirectory
var absolutePath = Path.Combine(@"c:\my\home\toys\", @"..\work\FilesDirectory" );
```

Note: you need to know what location the path is relative to. I.e. if it relative to executable use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` as base path.

Answer (score 2):

If relative path represents your Project Debug folder then you can use:

```
string relativePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "work\FilesDirectory"
```

Or you can also use `config` file to save your path and use `string.Join()` but its better to use `Path.Combine` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [Directory.GetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

```
DirectoryInfo parentDirectoryInfo = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
string []AllFiles = Directory.GetFiles(parentDirectoryInfo.FullName);
```

Hope I helped!