# c# cant locate images

Tags: c#, image, file, directory

i have this piece of code

```
string [] ImgLocation =
    Directory.GetFiles(@"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic\", " *.png",
                       SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

it's supposed to give me the location of all the image files inside the folder.However it doesn't work at all, it just gives me 0 strings. Why is that ?
The images location is : **_Poker\Poker\bin\Debug\Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic**

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what directory do the files reside in...?

Comment: added the location of the images in my question

Comment: You have a space. Change it to `"*.png"` instead of `" *.png"`.

Comment: @Rob - A good reminder to check the simple things first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259583/how-to-get-files-in-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetFiles` needs an absolute file path in order to work in a reliable way. Get it from Reflection (through the `Assembly` class)

```
string exeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
string fullPath = Path.Combine(exeDir, @"Assets\Cards\Pack_Classic");
string[] ImgLocation = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

`exeDir` is your `bin\Debug` folder.

---

Note: `GetFiles` works also with relative paths starting at the current working directory. The problem is that you don't always know where that one is! It can be different from the directory where the executable resides.