# How to use resources and files in C#

Tags: c#, file

I have a program that consists of images. I want to put some images in a folder and show the content of that folder dynamically. the program should be portable. What should I do? I tried the following code but did not work:

```
String path = "Resources/Location.txt";
String path2 = "/IconImagesForDummies/Icon";
ObservableCollection<IconImagesForDummies> icons = new ObservableCollection<IconImagesForDummies>();
String[] lines = null;
if (File.Exists(path))
   lines = File.ReadAllLines(path, Encoding.Unicode);
if (lines != null)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; ++i)
   {
        String str = path2 + @"/" + lines[i];
        if (File.Exists(str))
           icons.Add(new IconImagesForDummies() { Name = str });
   }
}
else
   throw new Exception("The Location.txt which stores the location of icons is missing");
if (icons.Count == 0)
   throw new Exception("There is no icon image");
```

Location.txt contains the name of images. My problem is that the program could not find the Location.txt. I have inserted Location.txt in resources. I have to mention that I also used another approach. I made a new folder and instead of `String path = "Resources/Location.txt";`, I used the folder name but it did not work too. What should I do?

Comment: I think you are having a problem with your relative path. Debug this `if (File.Exists(path))`. Does the path exists? You might want to read this to get a better understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259583/how-to-get-files-in-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Natrium actually it does not exits and the problem is that in my solution explorer it exists but not in the output file, that is why I used the resources but again not working

Comment: @Natrium actually I also do not know how to put a folder beside the executable program with code

Comment: Did you set the Property `Copy to output folder` of the `Location.txt` file? (To `copy always` or `copy if newer`)

Comment: @BojanB I did so but no result

Comment: Console Application or WinForm?

Comment: What did you set in the `build action` property?

Comment: @RichaGarg It is WPF

Comment: @BojanB its build action is resources, and I rebuild solution too, but still useless

Comment: Change your path to `String path = "./Resources/Location.txt";`

Comment: @RichaGarg still not working

Comment: Try changing the `build action` to `content` and `copy to output folder` to `copy always`

Comment: @BojanB Thanks, It did the job, please answer to close the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is not copied into the output folder of the project, try setting the `build action` property to `content` and make sure the `copy to output folder` property of the file is set to either `copy always` or `copy if newer` - depending on the requirements of the project.

Setting the `build action` as `Resource` in a `WPF` Project compiles the file in to the assembly or executable. That is why such a file will not be found in the output folder.

From MSDN:

> Resource Files: Data files that are compiled into either an executable
>   or library WPF assembly.