# Relative path to a file in C#?

Tags: c#

I've been working on an assignment for college which involves reading in some variables from a CSV file. I've completed my code and have everything working.

When referring the the CSV file I use a line of code similar to the foloowing:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\FILE\LOCATION\ON\DISK\FILE.CSV")
```

The only problem is that when i submit my code to be graded, obviously when who ever is marking the code tries to compile and run it will be greeted with an unhandled exception.

Can I place the CSV somewhere in the project folder and refer to it with a relative path (as can me done in HTML)?

I've tried using answers to similar questions on this site, but I'm pretty new to programming and don't understand some of the answers.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is already answered, all you need is google:  [How to get files in a relative path in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259583/how-to-get-files-in-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You could use a file open dialog to have the user tell your app where the file is

Comment: Have your program read from standard input, that way it can read the data from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your csv file into your solution folder as content and select `Copy to Output Directory` as always.

then call your code

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"FILE.CSV");
```

[image]

Comment: I would use right click solution in Solution Explorer. Select Add -> Exisitng Item. Then choose your file. The proceed as Simonare answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259583/how-to-get-files-in-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1 will help you more