# File ReadAllText is getting a wrong path (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, file, json.net

I have a local project that in the future will be in a pipeline.
Because of this, I need to use a relative path to get and read a json file.
But using the **File.ReadAllText** I'm obtaining the following answer:

```
> File.ReadAllText("MyJsonFiletoRead.json", Encoding.Default) 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\15071\MyJsonFiletoRead.json'
```

Note that 'C:\Users\15071' is not the project folder, this is my windows user folder.
My struct is here:

```
C:\Projetcs\MyProjectTest  -->> Project folder

C:\Projetcs\MyProjectTest\MyClass.cs  -->> The class where I'm calling the ReadAllText

C:\Projetcs\MyProjectTest\MyJsonFiletoRead.json -->> My json file that I'm trying to find
```

I have tried the following commands to check my PATH, but all answer is wrong:

```
> Environment.CurrentDirectory
 "C:\\Users\\15071"

> Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
 "C:\\Users\\15071"

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
"c:\\program files (x86)\\microsoft visual studio\\2019\\community\\common7\\ide\\commonextensions\\microsoft\\managedlanguages\\vbcsharp\\languageservices\\DesktopHost\\"
```

Has somebody a solution to fix this?

Note: If I use the full path, it works:

```
File.ReadAllText("C:/Projetcs/MyProjectTest/MyJsonFiletoRead.json", Encoding.Default)
```

Comment: How are you running your program? And where is it located?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get files in a relative path in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259583/how-to-get-files-in-a-relative-path-in-c-sharp)

Comment: My project is located in: C:\Projetcs\MyProjectTest\ and I'm running using the NUNIT (it's an automation test project). But to test without running tests, I tried the commands above using C# interactive.

Comment: @k_pedron but do you also start the executable from that directory?

Comment: where are located the running program? (not you pojrect, just the "exe file" )

Comment: @Paulo I don't have a exe file, because this is an automation project, where I will run test routines.

Comment: Are you using Resharper?

Comment: @Paulo No, I don't know about.

Comment: tried to do this:

 [Test]
         public void ExportationTest()
         {
       Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
           var evan= System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
             //...           
         }

Comment: @Paulo This returns:   evan "C:\\Projetcs\\MyProject\\bin\\Debug"

Comment: @Paulo I don't know why it is getting \bin\Debug. Do you know?

Comment: is getting \bin\debug because your program are running on this folder. 

is correct now! by default all aplications in debug mode on visual studio execute in \bin\debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216905/discussion-between-k-pedron-and-paulo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is located at the same folder of your executable file, you just need to pass the file name:

```
File.ReadAllText("MyJsonFiletoRead.json", Encoding.Default);
```

If the file is located at a relative path from the folder where your executable file is located, you can get the Assembly Location and combine it with a relative path:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "..\\..\\MyJsonFiletoRead.json");
File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.Default);
```

Comment: thanks! Exactly the file is located at a relative path... then doing your second suggestion worked to me!

Answer (score -1):

You need to find the current folder and then read the file

```
var currentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
File.ReadAllText(currentFolder + "/MyJsonFiletoRead.json")
```

Comment: This not work. "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' ", I guess that is a problem with Assembly