# How do I do a filePath wich depens on the location of the .exe

Tags: c#, directory, path, filepath

I am doing a program which reads .txt files and I want to access those without having to change manually the filePath directory. I have it like this: "F:\TR\AppPathFinding\AppPathFinding\bin\Debug" Here I have the .exe file, which starts the program. Secondly, I want to access one folder with different .txt files. It is here: "F:\TR\AppPathFinding\AppPathFinding\bin\Debug\GrillSelection" and the .txt name is: "SetGrill1.txt".
How can I access this .txt without having to change the path manually?

```
filePath = @"F:\TR\AppPathFinding\AppPathFinding\bin\Debug\GrillSelection\SetGrill1.txt";
```

This is what I need to change.

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you always want to access the same folder that is located at your .exe. Using a relative path.

This is very well explained by [Kieren Johnstone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3259651/15986238).

```
string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\GrillSelection\SetGrill1.txt";
```